# How to efficiently implement an event loop?

Tags: c++, com, performance

**COM Object** (Server) sends **event notification** successfully to **COM Client**

**Without:**

- ATL
- MFC

How to efficiently get the **main thread** to **wait/sleep** (infinitely) until **COM Server** notifies the **COM Client** of a particular **event**?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454984/receiving-com-events

Comment: @Filip: Not quite, normal event handling has already been implemented - post advise() - now I'm looking for a loop (in main thread)...

Comment: I receive calls to the Sink's method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With event objects.

The main thread calls CreateEvent() in its initialisation to create an auto-reset event object.

The main thread then enters an event loop in which it calls MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() repeatedly.  ([here](http://sarathc.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/when-and-how-should-we-use-msgwaitformultipleobjects/) is an example of a message loop.)

And you generally *do* need to check for window messages, even if the main thread has no GUI.

In the client thread (the one that creates the sink object) call SetEvent() within the sink method, after any necessary state update.  This will wake up the main thread.

And read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/17/375307.aspx), if you haven't already.

Comment: @finnw: Will I have to use STA? The first (main) call to CoInitializeEx(STA) will call CreateEvent() and enter MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(). Will I create a another thread: CoInitializeEx(STA) to then call/create an instance of the sink object on event notification to then call SetEvent()?

Comment: @Atklin, that depends on the requirements of the source object.  The event loop can run in either STA or MTA.

Comment: @finnw: I've tried both and it works (according to OLEVIEW - the COM Server is "LocalServer32"). I'm I write in saying I need to create another thread? or from the main STA: create an instance of the sink object, call the relavent method, wait (event loop) until notified (as in above comment)...